# Binary division of odd number by 10 to float

Tags: math, floating-point, binary, division

I have a question about division by 10 in binary.
If I have *1/10 (11/10, 111/10, 1001/10... It is same.) the result is *.1 or *.101?

If I convert this problem to decimal, it is:

1/2=0.5

**1/10=0.101**

But if I calculate this in binary, it is:

1/10=0 (remainder 1)

0.10/10=0.10

so 
**1/10=0.1**

I tried to solve this problem using binary calculator. 
This calculator here http://www.miniwebtool.com/binary-calculator/ said that the result is 0.1. 
Calculator in my Android phone said 0.101.

So, what is right and why?

(sorry for my english)

Comment: In “1/10=0 (carry 1)”, I think you mean “remainder” instead of “carry”.

Comment: You're getting confused: `10` in decimal is **not** the same as `10` in binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One half is `0.1` in binary. I don't know how you have been using your Android phone calculator, but that is not the right way to use it. (`101` in binary is five, but that is not how you convert the digits after the decimal dot).

Answer (score 2):

Well... depends on how you look at it.

1/10<sub>10</sub> equals 0.1<sub>10</sub> equals approximately 0.00011<sub>2</sub>.

1/10<sub>2</sub> equals 0.1<sub>2</sub> equals 0.5<sub>10</sub>.